# Пароль для каждой странички с страницы login.php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, пароль

Имеется страничка login.php и еще 10 страниц (1.php,2.php...10.php), доступ к которым должен осуществляться через пароль с редиректом на эту страницу.

При этом к каждой странице разный пароль. Пароли хранятся в таблице в БД.

Как такое проделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы  сделал так:

1. надо для каждой страницы хранить разные сессии, например:

   стр. http://sitename/users - $_SESSION['users_login'];

   стр. http://sitename/news - $_SESSION['news_login'];
2. когда юзер заходит на страницу надо сделать проверку если он уже залогинился;
3. если не залогиненный - перенаправить на страницу логин с каким то get параметром (названия страницы например - users)
4. когда пользователь вводит логин/пароль, проверяется в зависимости от страницы (get параметр)
5. если данные правильные записать необходимые записи в сессию и редирект на предыдущую страницу (get параметр), если же данные не правильные - вывести ошибку